# I'm trying to write a program about statistics

Tags: c

My program require to write a program to in put the scores and do something else. I had already write 2 functions, 1 for input the scores ( 5 per line) and sorted it. Now I'm trying to calculate the frequency of the scores and print it out as a chart. I wrote a function but it not work.can anyone teach me how to fix.

There is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 30
int sort(const void *p, const void *q);
void output(int testscore[], int size);
void frequence(int testscore[], int size);
int main()
{
   int i;
   int testscore[SIZE] = {90, 85, 100, 50, 50, 85, 60, 70, 55, 55, 80, 95,         70, 60, 95, 80, 100, 75, 70, 95, 90, 90, 70, 95, 50, 65, 85, 95, 100, 65};
    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        testscore[SIZE];
    }
    printf("before sort\n");
    output(testscore, SIZE);
    qsort(testscore, SIZE, sizeof(int), sort);
    printf("\nafter sort\n");
    output(testscore, SIZE);
    return 0;
 }
int sort(const void *p, const void *q) {
    if (*(int*)p < *(int*)q) {
        return -1;
    }
    return *(int*)p > *(int*)q;
}

void output(int testscore[], int size) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%6d", testscore[i]);
        if ( i % 5 == 4 || ( i == size - 1)) {
            printf("%c", '\n');
    }
    else {
        printf("%c", ' ');

    }
   }

}
void frequence(int testscore[], int size) {
    int i, j, count = 0;
    char value;
    char frequency;
    printf("%15c %15c", "value", "frequency");
    printf("%15s %15s", "-----", "---------");
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        count=1;
        for(j=i+1;j<=SIZE-1;j++){
            if(testscore[i]==testscore[j] && testscore[i]!='\0'){
                count++;
                testscore[j]='\0';
          }
        }
        if(testscore[i]!='\0'){
            printf("%d is %d times.\n",testscore[i],count);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: "I wrote a function but it not work". What is the error/output?

Comment: the problem here is the 3rd function( frequency() ), it not print out the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct as far as i can see when i copied and run it, and ou need to call frequence in main function.

There are some formatting issue though.

Here is what i used in function frequence

```
void frequence(int testscore[], int size) {
int i, j, count = 0;
char value;
char frequency;
printf("\n");
printf("%5s %9s", "value", "frequency");
printf("\n");
printf("%5s %9s", "-----", "---------");
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
    count=1;
    for(j=i+1;j<=SIZE-1;j++){
        if(testscore[i]==testscore[j] && testscore[i]!='\0'){
            count++;
            testscore[j]='\0';
      }
    }
    if(testscore[i]!='\0'){
        printf("%3d     %d\n",testscore[i],count);
        }
    }
}
```

here is the o/p i got..Hope this is what you are accepting

```
before sort
90     85    100     50     50
85     60     70     55     55
80     95     70     60     95
80    100     75     70     95
90     90     70     95     50
65     85     95    100     65

after sort
50     50     50     55     55
60     60     65     65     70
70     70     70     75     80
80     85     85     85     90
90     90     95     95     95
95     95    100    100    100

value frequency
----- ---------
 50     3
 55     2
 60     2
 65     2
 70     4
 75     1
 80     2
 85     3
 90     3
 95     5
100     3
```